# IntelliJ shows the external library, but can't resolve the import (This is using Gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jackson, gradle-dependencies

Trust me, I have googled for 4 hours, so I've tried invalidate/restart, deleting the gradle/.cache folder, reimport the project, refresh all the gradble projects, even restarting the computer. None of them worked.

So here's the actual issue:
I have an old artifact called traac-core 2.4.0, it uses jackson 2.7.2. Then I haven another project called traac-java, that uses traac-core as the dependency. With this old setup, I can import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException with no problem:
[using traac-core 2.4.0, it has jackson 2.7.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctUjw.png)
[import jackson works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VCu8.png)

So now since jackson 2.7.2 has vulnerability issues, I updated it to 2.14.2 in traac-core, built/deployed the newer version (2.5.0) to jfrog. Then I updated my traac-java gradle build. Then the import doesn't work anymore:
[now using traac-core 2.5.0 with jackson 2.14.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XKbC.png)
[import doesn't work anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh5gs.png)

As I said at the beginning, I tried everything I could find online that made sense to me.

I've also tried using traac-core 2.3.0, which also has jackson 2.7.2, that doesn't work neither. It almost seems like for some reason the import is fixated with version 2.4.0, but I've cleared the cache.

Comment: For some reason I cant see the image, but anyway. Newer jackson (and not only) libraries have rewrited code (different packages and class names), so using them with newer version of other dependencies may lead to errors. The solution is to stick with the old ones and solve (or live with) the vulnerabilities or rewrite code to use newer (if code comes from 3rd party, than PR to 3rd party or cry in a corner). Edit: "made sense to me", in corner cases I try to do the opposite, sometimes works.

Comment: Hi @itwasntme, thanks for the reply. The pictures somehow become links, you can click into them. I checked the jackson method signatures, for those ones that I use they are the same. Actually, if I put dependencies in the traac-java project gradle, the code will work. So it looks like the transitive dependency didn't work. But they work for the old traac-core.

Comment: Can you build/run the project successfully? Also, try to close the IDEA, and remove the `.idea` in this project folder root (you could backup into another location before removing it). Open the IDEA to open this project to see if it helps.

Comment: Hi @LJreplica, I tried both, won't work.